# Парсинг .txt файла

Tags: java, синтаксический-анализ

Здрастите. 
Мне нужно найти в текстовом файле слово. Пример:

```
абажурчик   сущ неод ед муж им  125724
абажурчика  сущ неод ед муж род 219588
абажурчику  сущ неод ед муж дат 219589
абажурчик   сущ неод ед муж вин 219590
абажурчиком сущ неод ед муж тв  219591
абажурчике  сущ неод ед муж пр  219592
абажурчики  сущ неод мн им  1261349
абажурчиков сущ неод мн род 1261350
абажурчикам сущ неод мн дат 1261351
абажурчики  сущ неод мн вин 1261352
абажурчиками    сущ неод мн тв  1261353
абажурчиках сущ неод мн пр  1261354

абаз    сущ неод ед муж им  125725
абаза   сущ неод ед муж род 217778
абазу   сущ неод ед муж дат 217779
абаз    сущ неод ед муж вин 217780
абазом  сущ неод ед муж тв  217781
абазе   сущ неод ед муж пр  217782
абазы   сущ неод мн им  1261355
абазов  сущ неод мн род 1261356
абазам  сущ неод мн дат 1261357
абазы   сущ неод мн вин 1261358
абазами сущ неод мн тв  1261359
абазах  сущ неод мн пр  1261360

абазин  сущ одуш ед муж им  4155485
абазина сущ одуш ед муж род 4155486
абазину сущ одуш ед муж дат 4155490
абазина сущ одуш ед муж вин 4155487
абазином    сущ одуш ед муж тв  4155489
абазине сущ одуш ед муж пр  4155488
абазины сущ одуш мн им  4155491
абазин  сущ одуш мн род 4155492
абазинам    сущ одуш мн дат 4155494
абазин  сущ одуш мн вин 4155493
абазинами   сущ одуш мн тв  4155495
абазинах    сущ одуш мн пр  4155496
```

Я задаю, например, для поиска "абазы". Как только слово найдено мне надо вернуть "абаз    сущ неод ед муж им", т.е. самое первое слово в списке словоформ. Я делаю:

<!-- language: java -->

```
public class KazemirdoMatcher 
{
    KazemirdoConverter kC = new KazemirdoConverter();

    private String[] requestWords;
    private Pattern p;
    private Matcher m;

    public void KazemirdoMatcherFirst() {
     try {
      File morph = new File("/home/virus/Documents/Workplace/Eclipse/Kazemirdo/Morph.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader 
                (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(morph), "Windows-1251"));
      // TODO: when matchs return infinitive
      String line = null;
      String match;
      requestWords = kC.getRequestBuffer();
      //
      for (int i = 0; i < requestWords.length; i++) {
        match = requestWords[i];
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            p = Pattern.compile(match);
            m = p.matcher(line);
            if(m.find())
       // ????????????????????????????????????????????????  
        }
       br.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found:" + e);
            return;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:" + ex);
            return;
        }       
    }   
}
```

Как мне вернуть именно первое слово из списка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Вы уже проехали строку, которая содержит первую словоформу. Т.к. словоформы у вас сгруппированы и разделены пустыми строками, то запоминайте первую строку из группы и возвращайте ее при совпадении.

Если файл сам по себе небольшой, то загружайте его в память полностью, а словоформы сгруппируйте вместе. Так выборка будет работать быстрее.

А вообще здесь напрашивается дерево поиска, возможно суффиксное.

PS: Не надо компилировать `Pattern` каждый раз. Это достаточно сделать один раз перед циклом. В вашем случае паттерн вообще не нужен, т.к. можно использовать метод `String.startWith`. Работа вашего алгоритма зависит от порядка запрашиваемых слов. Т.о. возможнор ситуация, при которой алгоритм не вернет ничего для существующего слова. Например если масси запрашиваемых слов будет таким: `"абазы", "абажурчики"`

Comment: Файл весит 187Мб, поэтому я не решился его полностью загружать.

Мне придется каждый раз компилировать, потому что у меня в коде идёт запрос из нескольких слов (пишу интеллектуальную систему, вернее пародию на неё) и запросы постоянно разные.

Comment: @FedoraLinux Не понял, что именно вам нужно рассказать поподробнее.

187Мб - это не много. Хотя в будущем вам могут попасться куда более объемные файлы. Тогда можно будет читать их кусками. При этом, лучше сортировать и файл и входные слова.

Компилировать один раз перeд while достаточно. Вы же компилируете его при каждой итерации.

Comment: Да, всё понял, точно, вынес за while.
В общем, спасибо за помошь.

Answer (score 0):

А что за класс тако Matcher? Можно код увидеть?  
Так или иначе, на сколько я понял, результат нахождения нужной подстроки можно получить, проанализировав переменную m. m - экземпляр Matcher, в котором есть некий магический метод find(). Это метод наверняка ищет нужную подстроку в очередной считанной строке. Осталось только понять как оно там все хранится и вывести. 
Если очередная считанная строка хранится просто как String, то предлагаю распарсить ее и вытащить нужное первое слово

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Это понятно, я это и делаю. Я не знаю как именно мне, после того, как я нашёл слово, вернуть то, что выше по списку.

Comment: @FedoraLinux, если есть String, то можешь воспользоваться методом split() аргументы которого - это разделители строки. в твоем случае пробелы или табуляции.    
Можешь тут посмотреть как люди это делают: http://www.sql.ru/forum/511922/razbor-stroki

Comment: Спасибо, split() умею пользоваться :)
Как мне, разделять весь файл split()'ом, загружая в память предлагаете?

Comment: Ну вот в цикле у тебя есть перменая line - это каждая твоя отдельная строка исходного файла. Как только сработало условие if(m.find()) предлагаю тебе внутри условия распарсить line и вытащить отутда первый элемент - это и будет нужное тебе слово.

Answer (score 0):

Думается, что можно узнать строку, в которой ты сейчас(X), прочитать файл снова, запоминая последний номер строки с переносом(пустой строки)(Y), остановить цикл, когда дойдешь до строки (X),тогда (Y+1) будет твоя искомая строка.

Comment: Лучше сразу запомнить первую строку после пустой.